# Pandas: How to set datetime type variable with specific interval as x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame with only three columns：timestamp (type: datetime), favorite_count, and retweet_count.
I want to draw a scatter plot to show how the number of favorite_count and retweet_count changed over time.

Here is my code:

```
x = df.timestamp
y = df.favorite_count

plt.scatter(x,y,alpha = 0.4)
```

The result:
[image: the scatter plot]

I met two problems:

1. Since the timestamp is like "2017-08-01 16:23:56+00:00", I cannot see the values in x-axis.
   How can I only show year-month, and set interval as 2 month in x-axis? (like: 2017-06 2017-08 ...)
2. I want to show two variables (favorite_count and retweet_count) in the same plot with different colors. How failed to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Although the sample data is not optimal, two of the issues can be addressed by the following.

1. You can use the `MonthLocator(interval=2)` to display the X-axis in two months.
2. Two types of data can be displayed in a graph with different Y-values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(df.index, df['favorite_count'], alpha=0.4)
ax.scatter(df.index, df['retweet_count'], alpha=0.4)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=None, interval=2, tz=None))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))

plt.show()
```

[image]